# JQuery-Plugin Datatables state from database

Tags: jquery, plugins, datatables

i need to load the state from database. I don´t know how i can change the state (ColReorder, ColVis etc.).
On first load there set the settings from my database in the `fnStateLoadCallback`.
Then i use on da button click only `oTableDrucken.fnReloadAjax();` and will set my new settings from Database but he don´t passed the `fnStateLoadCallback` function.

```
oTableDrucken = $('#table_drucken').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false, 
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
                "oColVis": {
                    "buttonText": "Zeige/Verstecke Spalten"
                },
        "sDom": 'r<"F"<"toolbar"RfC>>t<"F"i>',
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/sites/json_data.php",
                "fnServerData": function( sSource, aoData, fnCallback  ) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": sSource, 
                    "data": aoData, 
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (sdata,responseData) {
                    init_TableTools(oTableDrucken,responseData["logo"]);
        },
        "aoColumns": [          
            /* 1 ID */   { "sClass": "name", "mDataProp": "id" , "sName": "id"  },
            /* 2 Name */   { "sClass": "name", "mDataProp": "name" , "sName": "name"  },    
        ],
                "bStateSave": true,
                "fnStateSaveCallback": function ( oSettings, sValue ) {
            //Gives me the ColReorder Settings
            var valueObj = $(oTableDrucken).dataTable().dataTableSettings[0].aoStateSave[1].fn(null,sValue)+"}";
                    dataTableSettings = $.parseJSON(valueObj);
            return sValue;
                },
                "fnCookieCallback": function(sName, oData, sExpires, sPath) {
                    console.log("cookieCallback");   
                    return sName + "="+JSON.stringify(oData)+"; expires=" + sExpires +"; path=" + sPath;
                },
                "fnStateLoadCallback": function ( oSettings, oData ) {
                    oData.ColReorder = dataTableSettings.ColReorder;
                oData.abVisCols = dataTableSettings.abVisCols;
            return true;
            },
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "oLanguage": oCustomLanguage("drucken")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To store and load datatable settings in database, use fnStateSave and fnStateLoad functions (don't forget to set bStateSave to true and set async to false while loading)

I'm using jQuery to parse JSON, because if the settings are not saved in database, JSON.parse is resulting an error.

```
<script>
var oTable = $('.phonebook').dataTable( {
    "bStateSave": true,
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings, oData) {
        var o;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/loadState",
            async: false,
        }).done(function(data) {
            o = $.parseJSON(data);
        });

        return o;
    },
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/saveState",
            data: "data=" + JSON.stringify(oData),
        });
    },
});
</script>
```